# Raspberry not booting up after trying kernel compilation

Tags: pi-2, boot, kernel, boot-issues, noobs

I had placed fresh noobs on SD card and booted Raspberry Pi many times in the past. To install a custom kernel, I went with the follwing steps:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
sudo apt-get install bc
make bcmrpi_defconfig
```

and wrote the following commands to a script file

```
make
make modules
sudo make modules_install
```

and run the script as in the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1032794/Simple-I-O-device-driver-for-RaspberryPi). From the next day, the rapberry is not booting. When turning on the red and green led is just on. The green (ACT) led is not blinking.

Had tried with different SD cards which are working and tried the booting steps from scratch (FAT32 (in bootable and non bootable mode) Noobs contents placed inside the card). But the raspberry seems unhappy with me and she is not booting up. Hopefully not an SD Card contact issue with board as the stuff was working the previous night.

Any suggestions....Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Your commands was for Raspberry Pi 1 and Zero. If you are using Raspberry Pi 2 you should use these steps instead

```
sudo apt-get install git bc
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

then

```
cd linux
KERNEL=kernel7
make bcm2709_defconfig
```

and then

```
make -j4 zImage modules dtbs
sudo make modules_install
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb /boot/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/zImage /boot/$KERNEL.img
```

Based on the [Raspberry Pi Documentation Page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md)

That being said, I'm not really sure why the page said to install `git` AND `bc` as `bc` is a calculator program IIRC. I thought about installing `git-bc` would be more appropriate here

What I did is that I install `bc` because `git` is already included in Raspbian IIRC. Well, the weird part is that my compiled kernel works fine even though I though installing `bc` would be installing a calculator. I hope somebody would comment on this.